# Invalid endLine error when analyzing maven project by using SonarQube

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I want to use SonarQube to analyze my project which is a multi-maven project.When I'm trying to do an analysis, I am obtaining fallowing error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project GlobalWebsite: Invalid endLine: 483. File [moduleKey=com.fitchratings:website, relative=src/main/webapp/creditdesk/sectors/perf_analytics/esf/deal_compare/dc.js, basedir=C:\global-website-legacy\src\website] has 482 lines. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project GlobalWebsite: Invalid endLine: 483. File [moduleKey=com.fitchratings:website, relative=src/main/webapp/creditdesk/sectors/perf_analytics/esf/deal_compare/dc.js, basedir=C:\global-website-legacy\src\website] has 482 lines.***
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Invalid endLine: 483. File [moduleKey=com.fitchratings:website, relative=src/main/webapp/creditdesk/sectors/perf_analytics/esf/deal_compare/dc.js, basedir=C:\global-website-legacy\src\website] has 482 lines.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid endLine: 483. File [moduleKey=com.fitchratings:website, relative=src/main/webapp/creditdesk/sectors/perf_analytics/esf/deal_compare/dc.js, basedir=C:\global-website-legacy\src\website] has 482 lines.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.internal.DefaultStorable.validateLineArgument(DefaultStorable.java:57)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.duplication.internal.DefaultDuplication.originBlock(DefaultDuplication.java:57)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.duplication.internal.DefaultDuplication.originBlock(DefaultDuplication.java:40)
    at org.sonar.batch.cpd.JavaCpdEngine.saveDuplications(JavaCpdEngine.java:254)
    at org.sonar.batch.cpd.JavaCpdEngine.save(JavaCpdEngine.java:212)
    at org.sonar.batch.cpd.DefaultCpdEngine.runCpdAnalysis(DefaultCpdEngine.java:136)
    at org.sonar.batch.cpd.DefaultCpdEngine.analyse(DefaultCpdEngine.java:112)
    at org.sonar.batch.cpd.CpdSensor.execute(CpdSensor.java:96)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
```

I triggered the sonar analysis by using maven clean install and maven sonar:sonar.
**Versioning informations:**

SonarQube version: 5.1.2

SonarQube maven Plugin version: 2.6

Maven: 3.2.3

Comment: Looks like a bug in the copy/paste detection algorithm. Would you mind sharing the offending file (src/main/webapp/creditdesk/sectors/perf_analytics/esf/deal_compare/dc.js)?